# retrieving unique posts from distinct users every time in social newsfeed neo4j

Tags: neo4j, unique, social-networking, feed

Retrieving  unique posts every time in social newsfeed neo4j .

Right now i am using this script :-

```
MATCH (u:Users {user_id:140}),(p:Posts)-[:CREATED_BY]->(pu:Users)
WHERE
  (p)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u) OR
  (p:PUBLIC AND (u)-[:FOLLOW]->(pu)) OR
  (p:PRIVATE AND (p)-[:SHARED_WITH]->(u))
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:POST_MEDIA]->(f)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:COMMENT]->(c)<-[:COMMENT]-(u3)
RETURN
  {user_id:pu.user_id,
    firstname:pu.firstname,
    lastname:pu.lastname,
    profile_photo:pu.profile_photo,
    username:pu.username} as pu,
  p,
  collect({user_id:u3.user_id,
           profile_photo:u3.profile_photo,
           text:c.text}) as comment,
 collect(f) as file
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC LIMIT 25
```

The problem is that this script may return   multiple post from a single user 
and always show same posts.

Comment: In general, shortcut the query and return counts until you find where duplication happens. In particular, if your optional matches hit more than once (between them) you have multiple `p`:s.

Comment: can you write an answer with a code snippet , I doesn't understand what are you exactly saying